# How to split violin plot with separate confidence interval

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

How could I make violin figures like this. I want to include confidence interval
[image]
I can use the following code to plot split figures with quadrilles, but not mean and confidence. The data can be found here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/18GrncA2GmJd38tVGZZ5yylR6Cf61XsGp/view?usp=sharing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.violinplot(x="six.categories", y="non_poor", hue="year", data=df, split=True,
               inner="quart", palette={"2019": "b", "2020": "y"})
sns.despine(left=True)

plt.xticks(np.arange(6),["Nonpoor\nWhite", "Poor\nWhite", "Poor\nBlack", "Nonpoor\nBlack", "Poor\nHispanic", "Nonpoor\nHispanic"])
```

Comment: Please add the missing tags ([tag:python],[tag:seaborn]), the missing imports, and some link to dataset or sample data so this is reproducible ([mcve]).

Comment: I have updated the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine a `violinplot` and a `pointplot` for the desired result:

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                    data=tips, palette="muted", split=True, inner=None)
sns.pointplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                    data=tips, dodge=0.2, join=False, palette=['white'], ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Why the application on my data is different. The point of mean is big and no error bar. It works well on the tips dataset. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CtWlH9R3fBG3YV-dGwCBv10ZqZ9C0H-M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Since you have a very large sample size in most of your categories, the CI around the mean is very small and is hidden by the size of the point. You can shrink the marker using `scale=0.5` (adjust value as needed), which should help reveal the CI lines